# PHP Contact Form Has No Content

Tags: php, html, forms

The contact form I'm trying use is only sending the subject fields but no content.

I am using the following form:

```
<form id="contact-form-face" class="clearfix"      action="http://www.demo.com/php/contactengine.php">
                            <input type="text" name="email" value="Email"     onFocus="if (this.value == 'Email') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Email';" />
                            <textarea name="message" onFocus="if (this.value     == 'Message') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Message';">Message</textarea>
                            <input class="contact_btn" name="submit"     type="submit" value="Send Message" />
                        </form>
```

And the PHP post:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "myemail";
$EmailTo = "myemail";
$Subject = "";
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) { 
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly apprenticed

Comment: You can use the PHP `header` function in place of the meta redirects (if you have no output which it appears you dont). http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Sorry can explain what you mean by this please?

Comment: Would anyone know how i could use some sort of popup message to tell the user that the message has been sent instead of redirecting to a different HTML page? I would like to not take the user away from the page that contains the contact form if possible.

Comment: If you don't want to redirect my comment is useless.  Output the content you want the user to see in the success block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not defining a method on your form, this results in the "message" and "email" values being sent as GET parameters, this means they become query parameters as part of the URL. In order to get the form to send it's inputs to the $_POST, you must set the form action like so:

`<form id="contact-form-face" class="clearfix"      action="http://www.demo.com/php/contactengine.php" method="post">`

Furthermore you have a typo on the recieving end, where you look for  $_POST["Message"] but in the form you specify the name as "message". These must match.

//Edit - To implement an alert popup instead of a redirect change the `if` condition at the end of your script as follows:

```
if ($success) {
    ?>
    <script>
        alert("Success!");
    </script>
    <?php
}
else{
    ?>
    <script>
        alert("Failure!");
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Would you know how i could use some sort of popup message to tell the user that the message has been sent instead of redirecting to a different HTML page? I would like to not take the user away from the page that contains the contact form if possible.

Comment: JavaScript has the `alert` function that will achieve that. [http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

Comment: Could kindly show me how i would implement this into my project. Many thanks

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer that. Although you would be better off loading this script using Ajax - otherwise your popups will be over a blank page.

Comment: Thank you very much, very simple. Would you be able to explain how to use the Ajax approach? Im not very familiar with it

Comment: Not here, the comments really aren't a useful place for such things. There's a nice blog with a simple how-to here [http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form) - if you get stuck you can raise a new question here.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
$_POST['Message']
```

It should be:

```
$_POST['message']
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly - totally overlooked that.

Comment: Would you know how i could use some sort of popup message to tell the user that the message has been sent instead of redirecting to a different HTML page? I would like to not take the user away from the page that contains the contact form if possible.